# Duplicate values of a series of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel file that contains 3 columns. 
The first column contains the country/region codes, the second the country/region name and the third column contains the year.

In total I have 354 different values of country/region and 37 different years (from 1980 to 2016).

Here is a simplified example of my file. 
In this example there are 3 different values of country/region and 6 years (from 1980 to 1985).

```
|   COL A   |   COL B   |   COL C  |
+-----------+-----------+----------+
     AT     |  Austria  |   1980
     AT     |  Austria  |   1981
     AT     |  Austria  |   1982
     AT     |  Austria  |   1983
     AT     |  Austria  |   1984
     AT     |  Austria  |   1985
     AT     |  Austria  |   1980
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1980
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1981
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1982
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1983
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1984
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1985
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1980
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1981
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1982
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1983
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1984
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1985
```

What I would like is this:

```
|   COL A   |   COL B   |   COL C  |   COL D   |
+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+
     AT     |  Austria  |   1980   |     A
     AT     |  Austria  |   1981   |     A
     AT     |  Austria  |   1982   |     A
     AT     |  Austria  |   1983   |     A
     AT     |  Austria  |   1984   |     A
     AT     |  Austria  |   1985   |     A
     AT     |  Austria  |   1980   |     B
     AT     |  Austria  |   1981   |     B
     AT     |  Austria  |   1982   |     B
     AT     |  Austria  |   1983   |     B
     AT     |  Austria  |   1984   |     B
     AT     |  Austria  |   1985   |     B
     AT     |  Austria  |   1980   |     C
     AT     |  Austria  |   1981   |     C
     AT     |  Austria  |   1982   |     C
     AT     |  Austria  |   1983   |     C
     AT     |  Austria  |   1984   |     C
     AT     |  Austria  |   1985   |     C
     AT     |  Austria  |   1980   |     D
     AT     |  Austria  |   1981   |     D
     AT     |  Austria  |   1982   |     D
     AT     |  Austria  |   1983   |     D
     AT     |  Austria  |   1984   |     D
     AT     |  Austria  |   1985   |     D
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1980   |     A
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1981   |     A
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1982   |     A
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1983   |     A
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1984   |     A
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1985   |     A
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1980   |     B
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1981   |     B
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1982   |     B
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1983   |     B
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1984   |     B
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1985   |     B
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1980   |     C
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1981   |     C
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1982   |     C
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1983   |     C
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1984   |     C
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1985   |     C
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1980   |     D
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1981   |     D
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1982   |     D
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1983   |     D
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1984   |     D
     BE     |  Belgium  |   1985   |     D
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1980   |     A
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1981   |     A
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1982   |     A
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1983   |     A
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1984   |     A
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1985   |     A
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1980   |     B
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1981   |     B
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1982   |     B
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1983   |     B
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1984   |     B
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1985   |     B
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1980   |     C
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1981   |     C
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1982   |     C
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1983   |     C
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1984   |     C
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1985   |     C
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1980   |     D
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1981   |     D
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1982   |     D
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1983   |     D
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1984   |     D
    CH07    |  Ticino   |   1985   |     D
```

So what I want is:

- create a new column (column D)
- duplicate the 6 lines of each country/region 5 times (in order to have a total of 6 values for each value of column D)
- the values of column D are standard (in this example they are always A, B, C and D)

How can I do that? Doing this manually is too much work and you risk making mistakes.

Unfortunately it is difficult to explain in words, but I hope the example is helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Insert a column D, enter value 'A' in all the 354*37 cells.
2. Copy and paste this in a new sheet (say `sheet_2`)
3. Go back to the original page and replace 'A' in column D with 'B'
4. Append this to table in `sheet_2`
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 with remaining values ('C' and 'D' in example given)
6. Sort `sheet_2`.